# Uncaught typescript error: cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

## Error message

[image]

## Current usage

I am using typescript with vue, where the vue project was created using cli.

## Problem

I am trying to read a string within an object that was retrieved from firebase realtime database, but is displaying type errors in the console.

## Situation

I currently working on the navigation bar trying to get the text to display without errors. For this, I have all my textual data stored in a firebase realtime database.
[image]

I have a local vuex state that should store the textual data, a getter to retrieve it and then a mutator sync request to get the data from the database and store it in state as textual data.
[image]

In my App.vue file, I am calling the mutator sync request to get the textual data from the database and storing it in state.
[image]

Then, in my navigation.vue file, I am calling the textual data getter, to get the textual data object, to then reference the text I want.

[image]

It is strange because if I use a button to run a method that returns the result of calling the state for text item 'Home', it shows the correct string.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dylan the template is being rendered *before* your getter has been set (which is normal). The error message in the console is pointing to the problem, it's trying to read `.navigation` of undefined. So basically it's trying to read `$store.getters.getTextualData.header.navigation...` but on initial load, `header` does not yet exist (it's undefined as the error mentions).

My preference for solving this would be to have a computed property that returns the string once it's available, eg

```
computed: {
  homeButtonText() {
    return $store.getters.getTextualData?.header?.navigation.text.buttons.home
  }
}
```

it will return undefined until it's set. Alternatively you can return a default

```
computed: {
  homeButtonText() {
    return $store.getters.getTextualData?.header?.navigation.text.buttons.home || 'Home'
  }
}
```

The reason the method is returning the correct value is because the getter has had time to be set, so the text exists. Template rendering happens really early on. A good article and diagram can be found [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/introduction-to-vue-lifecycle-hooks/).

Within your template you can then update it as below,

```
<router-link class="nav__a" to="/">
  {{ homeButtonText }}
</router-link>
```

Comment: Hi @RuNpiXelruN, I have switched to computed properties like you have. I ran the code and it didn't work. I realised that I wasn't adding the ? after textualData and header. After adding it in, it worked. How come this is the case? What does the '?' do?

Comment: Hi @Dylan, it's called optional chaining in Javascript. The question mark is added so that if the property does not exist, 'undefined' will be returned..which is falsy. It's kind of like a safety that will always return something for you rather than throwing an error when it looks for that property but can't find it. More info on it below
https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es-next/javascript-optional-chaining-operator/